# I got an error during database migration in laravel9

Tags: migration, laravel-9

```
      catch (Exception $e) {
         throw new QueryException(
               $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
           );
       }
     }
```

1   C:\wamp64\www\laravelProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
")

2   C:\wamp64\www\laravelProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3308;dbname=laravelproject", "root", "", [])

Comment: Finally I solve this error

Answer (score 0):

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;   <-------------------------ADD THIS

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);  <-------------------------ADD THIS

}
```

}
This is the final code.